# Ошибка "JavaScript execution exceeded timeout" на iPad

Tags: ipad, javascript, safari

Падает ошибка

`JavaScript: Error
undefined
JavaScript execution exceeded timeout.`

Воспроизводится только на Safari в iPad. Как отловить? Как найти причину? Или хотя бы как узнать стэк вызовов этой ошибки?

И есть ли какие-то средства для отладки прямо в iPad? Что-то вроде FireBug существует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насчет отладки, но народ советует разбивать длительные задания на порции при помощи setInterval или setTimeout, чтобы могли отработать эвенты.

Ловите ошибку, используя Geolocation? =)

Comment: Я пока не знаю, что такое Geolocation. Попробовала запустить свою страницу на iPad и увидела эту ошибку в консоли Safari (выставила настройку "Debug Console is Enabled", но там кроме текста ошибки ничего не увидеть).

Comment: Что за страница? Что она считает?

Comment: У меня там Canvas и кнопки для работы с ним. Обновляется по таймеру. И канвас (перерисовывается), и кнопки (доступны/недоступны).